# Custom attributes in BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to use Beautiful soup to target a DIV with a non-standard attribute. Here's the DIV:

```
`<div data-asin="099655596X" data-index="1" class="sg-col-20-of-24 s-result-item sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-28-of-32 sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col sg-col-32-of-36 sg-col-12-of-16 sg-col-24-of-28" data-cel widget="search_result_1">`
```

I need to find_all DIV with the data-asin attribute, and get the asin as well. BS appears to support this feature, but what I am doing isn't working. Here's my code that doesn't work:

```
`rows = soup.find_all(attrs={"data-asin": "value"})`
```

How do I need to craft my BS in Python3.7 to find_all these DIV?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use Css Selector to get that.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<div data-asin="099655596X" data-index="1" class="sg-col-20-of-24 s-result-item sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-28-of-32 sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col sg-col-32-of-36 sg-col-12-of-16 sg-col-24-of-28" data-cel widget="search_result_1">
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
items=soup.select('div[data-asin="099655596X"]')
for item in items:
    print(item['data-asin'])
```

OutPut:

```
099655596X
```

OR

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<div data-asin="099655596X" data-index="1" class="sg-col-20-of-24 s-result-item sg-col-0-of-12 sg-col-28-of-32 sg-col-16-of-20 sg-col sg-col-32-of-36 sg-col-12-of-16 sg-col-24-of-28" data-cel widget="search_result_1">
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
items=soup.select('div[data-asin$="X"]')
for item in items:
    print(item['data-asin'])
```

Comment: @QHarr : Thanks you are right.I have provided end char options as well.

Comment: Okay, this gets the var from the div, but I need the content of the div. I am working with the Amazon search results page as the raw HTML, and that tag is the only one that seems to be unique to the item column/rows, and ideally they could be iterated. It's an ugly way to do it, but since Amazon made a change, all out Python Amazon libraries have ceased to work :(

Comment: I think what you were looking after to the given tag and attribute value I have provided the solution.I don’t understand what else you are looking after?

Comment: If you try the or option it will give all the value.

Comment: Yes, it gives the value of the data-asin perfectly. Greatly appreciated. What I am looking for, is the content of the DIV, as in the HTML inside that DIV, with all the other DIVs that are in it. So in effect, I want to strip out those special DIV from the page, and iterate over them, so I can then parse the HTML there.

Comment: But in your example there is no content inside DIv.If want tag value just type item.text.strip() it will give you the tag value

Comment: Perfect, that's what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with also specifying the tag?  I've had no issue when specifying the tag in the syntax I.E.

```
rows = soup.find_all("div",attrs={"data-asin": "value"})`
```